# Radio-Button Checkboxes Not Lining Up in Mobile

Tags: css, checkbox, radio-button

I'm having an issue with my site: http://graber.hwpreview.com/schedule/ it looks amazing on the computer, but on mobile the checkboxes don't line up at all:

[image: Checkboxes all doing their own stupid thing]

Ideally, I'd like them all the float left and align correctly. I can't really provide the coding because it's split across a few different areas.

Answer (score 0):

Add a media query breakpoint at 480px and make the css property top:27px for the element #main-content .wpcf7-form label{} since you are using a element that replaces the actual checkbox also do tha same for the box when it is checked i.e the #main-content .wpcf7-form label:after tag property in the media query.

Comment: This works for getting them in line, but it doesn't work for floating them all left into a list, so some of the days don't align with their button. Check the site out again: http://graber.hwpreview.com/schedule/